# Acessing variables on JSON request to Mandrill API other than merge_vars

Tags: json, parsing, templates, merge, mandrill

I'm trying to combine Mandrill service with another API that can send http POSTs to it, to merge variables into a template and send an email. The issue is that it's hard to make this other API send a JSON object just like the one Mandrill's API is expecting.

The other API can easilly send flat JSONs like

`{"name":"some name","firstvar":"10","secondvar":"20"}`,

but it's hard to make it create a complex JSON, with inner arrays and so on.

Another issue with the JSON format understood by Mandrill is that, within global_merge_vars, name value pairs aren't paired:

```
[ { "name":"MyVariable" , "content":"123" } ,
  { "name":"SecondVariable" , "content":"321"} ]
```

Instead of:

```
[ { "MyVariable":"123" , 
    "SecondVariable":"321" } ]
```

Which makes things a bit harder.

So what I'd like to know is if it's possible for Mandrill to merge other variables than those within the global_merge_vars or merge_vars arrays and reference them by their name value relation.

If you know of another solution or service that would suite the case presented, I would also apreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to write code that takes the information from the other API that you're working with and convert it to the format required by Mandrill. It's not possible to pass Mandrill data that's not in the format it accepts and have it map to the correct formatting - there are just too many possibilities to make that a feasible functionality. You'll probably want to decode the JSON you're getting from the other API, and then construct the payload for Mandrill. It might be helpful to use the Mandrill API client for the language you're working with to make it easier, or a service like [Zapier](http://zapier.com) that pairs APIs without needing to know how to code.